# I need to improve a part of my mesh

Tags: mesh

I have been working on a face mask in blender for quite a while now. I almost reached my goal and learned a lot but cannot make the last step.

1) I have a mesh (pretty clean now) of a human face.

2) I'm selecting the edge of the face on the right side and move the edges away from the mesh. This way I create a kind of extruded mold. I'm stretching the mesh

3) I'm using the bisect tool to cut the extruded mold.

This is almost what I want to achieve. The goal is to print this model in  a 3d printer so that it can be used as a mold for a cake.

My remaining problem is that the tube part of my model does not have a nice mesh structure. It only comprises of 1 loop of very lengthy quads. 
All operators that I tried to apply to this part of the mesh fail and produce an unbelievable amount of noise and artefacts. Specifically, I cannot thicken this part using the solidify modifiers.

How can I create a nice mesh structure here?

[image: The original mesh]
[image: selecting the loop]
[image: extending/stretching the mesh]
[image: bisected mesh]
[image: closeup of the problematic mesh]

Comment: Could you try to decimate your mesh and work with a lot of less polygons? Would be easier to work

Comment: You can try to subdivide that extrusion with a bunch of loopcuts so that the resulting density of polygons is approximately the same as on the face; then use Sculpt mode > Smooth brush to smooth it. Another way could be to cut geometry on the first step with some smooth line (a curve or grease pencil stroke) using e.g. Knife Project and extrude the result; there should be less smoothening work required

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot give up any more details in the mesh of the face. @MrZak you say: "you can try to subdivide that extrusion with a bunch of loopcuts so that the resulting density of polygons is approximately the same as on the face"  How would I do that?

Comment: Easiest way to subdivide is to hover mouse cursor over long tiny extruded polygons which should be quads on the last screenshot above, press Ctrl+R and scroll the mouse wheel up

Comment: This is a common problem. For this the easiest way would be to sculpt it with dyntopo which also looks very organic for a face. You can also retopo the mesh after the sculpting process to get a mesh with a decent topology.

Comment: @Schamph dynotop is definetly what I was looking for. Thanky you so much!!!!

Comment: You´re welcome!